# csv files downloading as txt when using download attribute of <a> tag

Tags: html, anchor

I am using the download attribute of the a tag to force the download of files, it has worked fine for .docx, .py and .md files but .csv files are downloading as .txt files even though I mentioned the correct extension in the file name.

```
<a className='btn btn-secondary mr-3 submit' href={prefix_url + "/1_Reports.csv"} download = "1_Reports.csv">Download File</a>
```

The file keeps downloading as 1_Reports.txt

Comment: Are the MIME types on your server setup for CSV properly?

Comment: @j08691 This file is present on github and I am using the 'download_url' provided by github api as the url. The other files with extensions that had accurate downloads were also present on Github.